# How to mod_rewrite url with subdomain and change extension

Tags: seo, mod-rewrite, domain-extension

I need to change the pattern of my url from the normal path into a subdomain. I tried write the .htaccess but it's not work.

`http://hello.com/sos/article.php?id=1&title=this-is-a-title.php`

From the url above I want to:

1. Change the pattern to call the page so I remove `sos` before the domain as a subdomain. So I'd got `http://sos.hello.com/`
2. I need the variable to be replaced with forward slash and suffixed with `.sos`. As the story is about warning : `article/1/this-is-a-title.sos`

I wish I could have something like this:
`http://sos.hello.com/article/1/this-is-a-title.sos`

So I wrote :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.sos$ /article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

And guess what! It's not work. Please point me out. What I've done wrong???

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Change to use subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sos\.hello\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sos.hello.com/article/$2 [R=301,L]

# Change to pretty URL path if no query string parameters present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !id [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !title
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sos.hello.com/article/ [R=301,L]

# Change to pretty URL path if query string parameters are present
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /article/$1

# Change query string parameters into path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/article/article.php)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)&title=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^article/article.php(.*) http://sos.hello.com/article/%2/%3?

# Replace .php with .sos
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ $1.sos [L]
```